# C# Change DataGrid Cell Value based on matching text box string

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, datagrid

I have a datagrid with three columns:

**KIT Number**, **Part Number** and **Qty**.

I'm writing a barcode scanner winform application whereby when a Part Number is scanned into a TextBox, if that matches a Part Number in a DataGrid, the `Qty` will be reduced by 1. Once `Qty` reaches 0 the row will highlight green and not allow `Qty` to be reduced anymore.

What would be best way to go about doing this? My first thought is a loop that searches the DataGrid. Is there anything more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried foreach loop there ?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
   if (item.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == txtPart.Text)
    {
       item.ReadOnly = false;         
       this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = convert it to int and minus -1;
    }
}
```

Same way you can check quantity value if it is zero than color it green.

Answer (score 0):

①Once you get the Part Number Input, use LINQ to locate the item with the specific Part Number.
②Check the Qty's Value. If !>0, turn the row's bg into Green or whatever.

```
YourItemSourceType temp = YourDataGridItmesSource.Where(ThatItemYouWant => ThaItemYouWant.PartNumber == InputPartNumber).FirstOrDefault();
//①:Get the item with specific Part Number.
//use'?.' in case there is no match for InputPartNumber.
if(temp?.Qty !< 0)
{
    temp.Qty --;
    NotifyTheChange();
    //update your view  if you need to update it manually
}
else
    CalculateTheItemPositionAndPaintItGreen();
    //②
```

Comment: Is there a non LINQ option? I'd rather not use it as I'm reasonably new to C#

Comment: Many useful tools are invented just to simplify the problem,so does LINQ, since it can deal with both simple and complex situation in an elegant way(easier to read,  fewer bugs).

Comment: So this goes in the KeyDown event where I find the part number? `String searchValue = textBox2.Text;
                int rowIndex = -1;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in iCBOMHDataGridView.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells["0"].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
                    {
                        <temp messgae box here>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       <temp messgae box here>
                    }
                }`